# How do I validate an TextBox to only allow numbers.

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012

I need a text box that only allows numbers (on an .aspx webpage - ASP.NET C# Framework 4.5 - Visual Studio 2012)

Here is what I started with, which I converted to C# -- it mostly worked, but I believe due to a framework modification, the OnValidating part does not work in C#:

Here is the original site that got me going: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4a2d7afa-a7d1-4886-9366-13786e7ddfd2/allow-only-numeric-entries-in-textbox?forum=vblanguage

Here is the original VB:

```
Public Class NumericTextbox  
Inherits TextBox  

Public Sub New()  
    mAllowedNumberStyles = Globalization.NumberStyles.Any  
    mCultureFormat = Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat  
End Sub 

Private mAllowedNumberStyles As System.Globalization.NumberStyles  
Public Property AllowedNumberStyles() As System.Globalization.NumberStyles  
    Get 
        Return mAllowedNumberStyles  
    End Get 
    Set(ByVal value As System.Globalization.NumberStyles)  
        mAllowedNumberStyles = value  
    End Set 
End Property 

Private mCultureFormat As System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo  
Public Property CultureFormat() As System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo  
    Get 
        Return mCultureFormat  
    End Get 
    Set(ByVal value As System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo)  
        mCultureFormat = value  
    End Set 
End Property 

Private mNumericValue As Double 
Public Property NumericValue() As Double 
    Get 
        Return mNumericValue  
    End Get 
    Set(ByVal value As Double)  
        mNumericValue = value  
        Text = mNumericValue.ToString  
    End Set 
End Property 

Protected Overrides Sub OnValidating(ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs)  
    MyBase.OnValidating(e)  
    If Not e.Cancel AndAlso TextLength > 0 Then 
        If Not Double.TryParse(Text, mAllowedNumberStyles, mCultureFormat, mNumericValue) Then 
            e.Cancel = True 
        End If 
    End If 
End Sub 

End Class
```

Here is my C# version of the same code (largely thanks to telerik Code Converter!) -- There are 3 errors in the onValidating. See last method below (OnValdiating) for details on the errors  :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
//using System.Web;



using Microsoft.VisualBasic;
//using System;
using System.Collections;
//using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI;

namespace Clarity.Utilities
{
    public class NumericTextBox : TextBox
    {
        public NumericTextBox()
        {
            mAllowedNumberStyles = System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Any;
            mCultureFormat = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat;
        }

        private System.Globalization.NumberStyles mAllowedNumberStyles;
        public System.Globalization.NumberStyles AllowedNumberStyles
        { //get;set;}
            get { return mAllowedNumberStyles; }
            set { mAllowedNumberStyles = value; }
        }

        private System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo mCultureFormat;
        public System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo CultureFormat {
        //private System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo mCultureFormat;
        //public System.IFormatProvider CultureFormat         {//get;set;}
            get { return mCultureFormat; }
            set { mCultureFormat = value; }
        }

        private double mNumericValue;
        public double NumericValue
        {
            get { return mNumericValue; }
            set
            {
                mNumericValue = value;
                Text = Convert.ToString(mNumericValue);
            }
        }

        // This part generates three errors -- 
        // 1) 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox' does not contain a definition for OnValidating'
        protected override void OnValidating(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            // 2) 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox' does not contain a definition for OnValidating'
            base.OnValidating(e);
            if (!e.Cancel && Text.Length > 0)
            {
                // 3) The best overloaded method match for 'double.TryParse(string, 
                //System.Globalization.NumberStyles, System.IFormatProvider, out double)' 
                //has some invalid arguments        
                if (!double.TryParse(Text, mAllowedNumberStyles, mCultureFormat, mNumericValue))
                {
                    e.Cancel = true;
                }
            }
        }

    }
}

    //=======================================================
    //Service provided by Telerik (www.telerik.com)
    //Conversion powered by NRefactory.
    //Twitter: @telerik
    //Facebook: facebook.com/telerik
    //=======================================================
```

Comment: Just to check (as I'm not 100% certain) but are you converting windows form code to web form code?

Comment: I edited the tags out of your title. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From http://forums.asp.net/t/1832924.aspx I found the answer that I went with... all answers got me going in the right direction... 6 ways to skin this cat!!! Thanks to all for the info!!

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
// Except only numbers and dot (.) for salary textbox
function onlyDotsAndNumbers(event) {
    var charCode = (event.which) ? event.which : event.keyCode
    if (charCode == 46) {
        return true;
    }
    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
        return false;

    return true;
}
//Except only numbers for Age textbox
function onlyNumbers(event) {
    var charCode = (event.which) ? event.which : event.keyCode
    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
        return false;

    return true;
}

 // No alphabets for Emp No textbox
function noAlphabets(event) {
    var charCode = (event.which) ? event.which : event.keyCode
    if ((charCode >= 97) && (charCode <= 122) || (charCode >= 65) && (charCode <= 90))
        return false;

    return true;
}
```

```
Salary:<asp:TextBox ID="txtSalary" runat="server" onkeypress="return onlyDotsAndNumbers(event);"> </asp:TextBox><br />
Age:<asp:TextBox ID="txtAge" runat="server" onkeypress="return onlyNumbers(event);"></asp:TextBox><br />
Emp no:<asp:TextBox ID="txtEmpNo" runat="server" onkeypress="return noAlphabets(event);"></asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 3):

An alternative to the other answers is to use an ASP.net [Range Validator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.rangevalidator%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

An example of it in action is:

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
 <asp:RangeValidator ID="RangeValidator1" runat="server" 
        ErrorMessage="RangeValidator" MaximumValue="10000" MinimumValue="0" ControlToValidate="TextBox1"
        Type="Integer"></asp:RangeValidator>
 <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
```

The validator is set to check an integer value between 0 and 10000. You could also combine this with a RequiredField validator if you wanted a mandatory check also.

Comment: Great answer - Thanks! I ended up going with the javascript I posted below as I have to use this several places on the page and the js will be easier to maintain.

Answer (score 2):

If your using JQuery you can do this.

```
$('#YourID').on('keypress', function (ev) {
        var keyCode = window.event ? ev.keyCode : ev.which;

        if ((keyCode < 48 || keyCode > 57) && keyCode != 46) {
            //codes for backspace, delete, enter            
            if (keyCode != 0 || keyCode != 8 && keyCode != 13) {
                ev.preventDefault();
            }
        }
    });
```

This will only, allow numbers, backspace, delete, and enter

Comment: This is going to be the best implementation. What you're dealing with is a client side issue, so solving the problem on the client side is the best approach. Obviously, you need to validate that the submitted data is only numbers in case the user has disabled JavaScript etc.

Comment: This is an awesome answer.. I am using an <asp:TextBox>, so I used a different version of the exact same thing. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction! (This is the post that I needed to refine my search to get the best answer for my scenario.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex to do this

This will allow only digits or no digits:

```
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(textbox.Text, "^[0-9]*$")
```

If you want to do it on the fly use javascript or place it inside your `<input>` tags.

```
<input type="text" name="example" pattern="^[0-9]*$">
```

Comment: Great idea/info -- I ended up going with the javascript I posted below. Seemed easiest, very straightforward.